# Search user in LDAP(Wildfly)

Tags: ldap, wildfly, wildfly-10

My application is using LDAP for user loging.

Wildfly config:

```
<security-domain name="LDAPAuth">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="LdapExtended" flag="required">
            <module-option name="java.naming.factory.initial" value="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"/>
            ....
        </login-module>
        <login-module name="Database-role" code="Database" flag="optional">
            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
            .....
        </login-module>
        <login-module name="Database-default" code="Database" flag="optional">
            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
            ....
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

My question is how to search ldap users in app? I want to add possibility to search other users in ldap(for already logged users).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **could** connect to WildFly management API and read security domain configuration, but you **should not** do this.

Don't mix server management configuration and application configuration if you have other way.

Provide the LDAP configuration to application (e.g. context parameters in the deployment descriptor or use a property file) and then do sth. like:

```java
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapUrl);
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, user);
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
final LdapContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
final SearchControls searchControls = new SearchControls();
searchControls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
NamingEnumeration<?> namingEnum = ctx.search("dc=mycompany,dc=example", "(uid=*)", searchControls);
while (namingEnum.hasMore()) {
    // TODO
}
namingEnum.close();
ctx.close();
```